# Do finished threads have impact on a main program in winapi?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, gif

I'm working on small gif images viewer program. Since it takes a few seconds to decode the whole gif, I decided to use separate thread for decoding it in a background and (after appropriate tuning) allow the program to start smoothly displaying gif just after the launch. Using the first method, the program waits (few seconds) till the whole gif is parsed and then starts displaying it and everything works fine. Using the second method the program starts displaying the gif just after the first frame is loaded, then displays in grotesque way (since it has not been tuned) the frames that have been loaded till all of them are loaded. I use exactly the same parse and display functions in both methods, but the problem is, that in threads method, after the threads are finished and exit, the gif displaying is little slower, where should be the same as in the first method since the threads have exited. So my question is, if is it possible that the threads are doing a permanent impact on the process, even although they have finished?
( I'm sure they are exiting because I use CloseHandle function and it returns 1. )

I'll copy some code as well, but they are very smart excerpts and dont say much:

Please note that i convert the frames to hbitmaps to display them on window
First method:

```
gifImage->findFrames();
frames_bitmaps=(HBITMAP *)malloc(gifImage->getFramesQuantity()*sizeof(HBITMAP));
for(int i=0;i<gifImage->getFramesQuantity();i++)
{
    frames_bitmaps[i]=gifImage->getFrame(i)->convertToDIB(hwnd);
}
startDisplay();
```

second method:

```
//"main" function:
DWORD id1,id2;
findThread=CreateThread(NULL, 0, startFindFrames, (void*) this, 0, &id1);
fillThread=CreateThread(NULL, 0, startfillBitmaps, (void*) this, 0, &id2);

//the actual functions (these in CreateThread func are static for compatibility and contain the following ones):
void GifExplodeWindow::findFrames()
{
    gifImage->findFrames();
    loading_done=1;
}

void GifExplodeWindow::fillBitmaps()
{
    while(!loading_done)
    {
        int current_quantity=gifImage->getFramesQuantity();

        if(filled_bitmaps<current_quantity)
        {
            frames_bitmaps=(HBITMAP *)realloc(frames_bitmaps,current_quantity*sizeof(HBITMAP));

            for(;filled_bitmaps<current_quantity;filled_bitmaps++)
            {
                frames_bitmaps[filled_bitmaps]=gifImage->getFrame(filled_bitmaps)->convertToDIB(hwnd);


                if(filled_bitmaps==0 && current_quantity!=0)
                {   
                    display_state=PREVIEW;
                    changeDisplay();
                }

                filled_bitmaps++;
            }
        }

        Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

I wrote the code at first just to make it working, when I'll solve my problem Ill correct it, but for now only important is what it does

Comment: Closing a thread handle has no relevance to whether or not the thread exited. You should probably post the rest of your thread functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was lying in the code, very shameful fault.
In the inner for loop in the fillBitmaps() function I was incrementing the filled_bitmaps variable twice each loop and this caused the weird display.

Answer (score 1):

### RECOMMENDATION:

> Do finished threads have impact on a main program in winapi?

Can you be more specific? What kind of effect do you exactly mean?

I recommend to expand the question, by elaborating it with additional code example, additional and **precise** description of what your problem is.

This is just a bit too general question, in my opinion.

### THE ANSWER:

After reading through your question, I have came to the same conclusion as others, and that is that maybe you haven't done the proper thread synchronization.

You see,when using `CloseHandle`, you **DO NOT** close the thread, and you **DO NOT** start the thread shutdown.

I wish if things were that easy :)

From MSDN ( see here, in the Remarks section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ):

> *Closing a thread handle does not terminate the associated thread or
>   remove the thread object*.

`CloseHandle` just closes the handle, but you need additional instructions in your code to **close** your thread function.

This is usually done via event object that is set, when you want to stop the thread, or you can use a boolean variable.

I think that these are your best bet, judging from the content of your question.

Also you should read about thread synchronization as well, if your thread function can be started **multiple** times in the program, and **all/some** those functions **can access and modify** the same resource ( in your case the GIF picture ).

Reading through your question, I have concluded that your thread function has no GUI, nor it has the need to display `MessageBox`, or dialog box. Therefore it is safe to assume, that the type of your thread is what is usually called "Worker Thread".

Since your question is not entirely clear to me, I only assume, that you have approached this topic with not enough experience.

Some of these articles/links might help you to solve your problems:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552/Using-Worker-Threads

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In the last article, you may want to start with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

more concretely with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also, pay attention to synchronization objects, you might find mutex and critical section handy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

These two code examples might help you, as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

### SUMARY:

I have given you a lot of links to go through, so I will try to make things easier for you, in this section, as much as I can:

Your main thread ( GUI, dialog box ... ) should start the thread function, and **wait** for it to finish.

In order for main thread ( GUI, dialog box ) to know when your thread function is finished, it must receive some sort of notification from it.

This is usually done via custom message sent from the thread function to the main thread ( GUI, dialog box ) via `PostMessage` API, or by setting the Event Object.

Then, you must wait in your main thread ( GUI, dialog box... ) for that thread function to exit using WaitForSingleObject, or WaitForMultipleObjects if you have multiple threads started.

ONLY then, can you close the thread handle.

Also, it would be wise to set thread handle to NULL, just to be safe.

You should try to find this book via Internet:

*Programing Windows 5th edition, by Charles Petzold.*

In chapter 20, you have a code example that synchronizes the thread execution the way I have described, so try to find that book, buy it/borrow it from a friend...

( maybe source code alone can help you, download it from here:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/books.html, I think it is free, but check it, just in case ).

*Also, one important note:*

*Don't close your thread with `TerminateThread` or `ExitThread` API. Thread function should return normally, it should not be forcibly aborted.*

With code example from Petzold's book, and just by reading through those links and my answer, you should understand how thread synchronization works, and maybe you will be able to solve your solution.

If you have further questions, ask me for help, and I willl try to help you.

Good luck!

Regards.

Comment: A lot of very useful information, thank you very much! I've been not answering for long time because I decided I can't make any skips and have to grasp necessary knowledge to continue. My problem wasn't related with the system, but the knowledge allowed me to ensure that the threads are fine, so I could calmly look on my code. Although the topic question doesn't make a lot of sense, hope more people will look here and upvote you :)

Comment: I am glad I was helpful, and am even more glad that you have solved it. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm sure they are exiting because I use CloseHandle function and it returns 1"

It does not work that way. CloseHandle has no effect on the thread and tells you nothing about the thread. If you need your main thread to know when a secondary thread has finished you must provide some signaling from the secondary thread. One way is to have that thread use PostMessage to notify the main thread when it has finished.